# Using the response Body from a .NET API call as the POST Body in another API Call

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an internal API built in .NET Core 2.0 that has one GET Method, where I am getting a list of employees and just returning a JSON list. being new to .NET, how can I use these results in a subsequent POST call to an external API where we have to upload these users?

EmployeeController.cs

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Employee")]
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private readonly EDWContext _edwContext;

    public EmployeeController(EDWContext context)
    {
        _edwContext = context;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetAllEmployees")]
    public ActionResult GetAllEmployees()
    {


        var results = from email in _edwContext.EmployeeEmail
                      join emp in _edwContext.Employee on email.EmployeeID equals emp.EmployeeID
                      join eol in _edwContext.EmployeeOfficeLocation on emp.EmployeeID equals eol.EmployeeID
                      join jc in _edwContext.JobCode on emp.JobCodeID equals jc.JobCodeID
                      join lf in _edwContext.LocationFloor on eol.LocationFloorID equals lf.LocationFloorID
                      join ol in _edwContext.OfficeLocation on lf.OfficeLocationID equals ol.OfficeLocationID
                      join o in _edwContext.Office on ol.OfficeID equals o.OfficeID
                      where emp.EmployeeStatusID == 1 
                      || emp.EmployeeStatusID == 3
                      || emp.EmployeeStatusID == 4
                      where email.EmailtypeID == 1
                      select new
                      {
                          emp.EmployeeID,
                          emp.FirstName,
                          emp.MiddleName,
                          emp.LastName,
                          jc.JobCodeName,
                          email.EmailAddress,
                          o.OfficeName
                      };




        return Json(results.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: How does the upload get triggered? Is it a client action? Is the external endpoint accessed directly by the client or do you need to make the call from within your .NET application?

Comment: It was supposed to be an external endpoint, but that’s not the case, I have to manually push to the clients API on a reoccurring basis. I was trying to figure out how to use the same results without having to craft a very long manual post body